# How to make tree joins at the same time with Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I tried to make tree joins with this code, but didn't work...

```
$av = DB::table('rifcliente_filtro')
    ->join('clientes_incid', 'rifcliente_filtro.rif', '=', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
    ->where('clientes_incid.cat_cliente', 'AV')
    ->count();
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why are you use this way?. You should use simple laravel joins!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
$av = DB::table('rifcliente_filtro')
->join('clientes_incid', 'rifcliente_filtro.rif', 'clientes_incid.rif')
->join('incidencias','incidencias.rif','rifcliente_filtro.rif')
->where('clientes_incid.cat_cliente', 'AV')
->count();
```

Please refer Laravel docs